# CKEditor 'Source' button listener

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm Looking to disable a button outside of CKEditor during Source view. I've tried it many different ways, but can't seem to get it right.

My code:

```
var CKE = CKEDITOR.instances.textarea;
    CKE.setData(decodeURIComponent(htmlTEXT), function () {
        this.checkDirty();
    });

    CKEDITOR.on('key', function (ev) {
        var state = ev.editor.getCommand('source').state;
        console.log(state);
        if (state == true)
        {
         // disable button
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CKEDITOR.editor#mode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-mode) event listener ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/0zotgozf/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'my-editor', {
    toolbarGroups: [
        {"name":"document","groups":["mode"]},
        {"name":"basicstyles","groups":["basicstyles"]}
    ],
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.on( 'mode', function() {
                console.log( this.name + ' works in ' + this.mode + ' mode' );
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I ended up making a function to check the mode for 'source'.

```
    function checkSource() {
      if (CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.mode == 'source'){
        // this will disable the save button while in 'Source' mode.
        $('#SaveBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
      else{
        $('#SaveBtn').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');;
      }
```